# Eclipse window doesn't activate if it's minimized

Tags: eclipse, autohotkey

I'm using the following code which works fine; it swaps to the front if it's behind other windows, it opens if it's closed. However it doesn't swap to the front if it's been minimized.

```
!j::
    if WinExist("ahk_exe eclipse.exe")
    {
        WinActivate
    }
    else
    {
        Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe"
    }
    return
```

I have the same code for other programs which works fine if the window's been minimized. Why isn't it working for eclipse and how can I make it work?

Comment: The window is probably isn't *minimized* but hidden. Try [DetectHiddenWindows, On](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DetectHiddenWindows.htm). Otherwise this will become tricky and you'll need to restore it by sending a click event to its tray icon (there is a user function for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this working method:

```
!j::
    WinGetTitle, Title, ahk_class SWT_Window0
    if InStr(Title, "Eclipse") {
        WinActivate, ahk_class SWT_Window0
    }
    else
    {
        Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe"
    }
    return
```